# Why did people call Islam 'Muhammadanism' when it clearly states in the Qu'ran that Islam is the name of the religion?

Tags: history, names

[Quran 3:85](https://quran.com/3/85) states:

> وَمَن يَبْتَغِ غَيْرَ **الْإِسْلَامِ** دِينًا فَلَن يُقْبَلَ مِنْهُ وَهُوَ فِي الْآخِرَةِ مِنَ الْخَاسِرِينَ

This translates into:

> And whoever desires other than **Islam** as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers

This raises the question:

**Why did people call Islam 'Muhammadanism' when it clearly states in the Qu'ran that Islam is the name of the religion?**

<sub>( I don't know whether or not this is on topic. Please inform me if you think it is off topic and justify why)</sub>

Comment: Probably for the same reasons followers of Christ were called Christians, they might have followed the same naming convention, as you could tell this is an opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would fit better in history.SE, but anyway in Wikipedia it is said that the word comes from something meaning a "follower of Mohammad"

> The Oxford English Dictionary cites 1663 as the first recorded usage of the English term; the older spelling Mahometan dates back to at least 1529. The English word is derived from New Latin Mahometanus, from Medieval Latin Mahometus, Muhammad. It meant simply a follower of Mohammad.[5]

It might also be relevant, as quoted in wikipedia, that Christians mistakenly thought Muhammad was worshiped by Muslims:

> In Western Europe, down to the 13th century or so, Christians had a mistaken belief that Muhammad had either been a heretical Christian or that he was a god worshipped by Muslims

Mohammedan is more the synonym of "Muslim" while Mohammedism is the synonym of "Islam". This is quoted [here](http://wikidiff.com/mohammedanism/islam):

> The terms Mohammedan'' and ''Mohammedanism'' have been largely replaced by ''Muslim'' and ''Islam' since the 1950s

Source: [Mohammedan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammedan), [Mohammedism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/mohammedism)

Comment: It was a helpful/interesting statement as you remarked :...Christians mistakenly thought Muhammad was worshiped by Muslims. Even, I personally assume it might have been a kind of partial/spiteful calling to pretend (and prompting) that as if Muslims are worshiping a human (instead of Allah), but Alhamdolellah currently everyone knows that Muslims worship Allah.  God bless you for mentioning that.